# QGIS conditional formatting in symbology

Tags: qgis, symbology, conditional, formatting

[image]

These data are colored per column in excel using path: Home (tab)--> Conditional Formatting (styles)--> Colour scales--> Blue-White-Red Colour Scale

Each id represents a cluster on the analysis I am performing. Is it possible to use this conditional formating in QGIS symbology? So that the colours of my layout would look the same? Does anybody know the function used in excel?

[image: map -data2 column]

[image]

Comment: Where do you want to get such output ?

Comment: Are you looking to display data that is stored in a layer's vector attribute table on a map with graduated symbology, or are you simply interested in adding a table that looks like what you have in Excel?  If the latter you could take a snapshot of your Excel and paste it into a layout  If the former, you should try using graduated symbology applying a red to blue color ramp, and update your question for any problems you can't solve using that.

Comment: Also be aware you have two color ramps- in the "ascending" fields blue is highest whereas in the descending fields red is highest.

Comment: I want to display data stored in a layer's vector attribute table on a map with graduated symbology. I added a map to the question. I used a color ramp from red to blue from QGIS. Although you can see that in excel the values are very close to each other resulting in the same color of reds (see data2 column) (clusters id 16 17 19) what should I do to get graduated colors like excel?

Comment: It would be good to include the settings you used in QGIS to make the map that you show, and to make it a bit clearer what is unsatisfactory about it. At the moment it is some guesswork from our side which makes it difficult to give a good answer.

Comment: I am sorry if I am not making it clear to see I am trying to add more info about the question. I also added what I used in symbology

Answer (score 0):

Your data in column X is formatted differenly than that in column Z. The `0.039` in X is reddish and the `0.037` in Z is whiteish.

So my path forward would be:

0. choose one palette that fits all your data and note the min/max values and colors you would like to use
1. create a known formatting in excel that you control, e.g. using the methods described here https://www.howtogeek.com/734938/how-to-apply-a-color-scale-based-on-values-in-microsoft-excel/ . In a nutshell: create your own rule and set the extreme points (min/max) yourself.
2. use a QGIS renderer with the exact same colors and extreme points